# Can I use Bluetooth and headphone jack simultaneously

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 7plus. How can I simultaneously connect music to my headphone jack and my phone to a Bluetooth device? I am trying to play my music on my motorcycle through the stereo using the headphone jack while using my Sena Bluetooth headset to talk on the phone.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/101137/35933)

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done on any of the current iPhones running any standard version of iOS.  Maybe if you edit your question and add what you're trying to accomplish by doing this, someone might be able to provide an alternative.

Comment: I am trying to play my music on my motorcycle through the stereo using the headphone jack while using my Sena Bluetooth headset to talk on the phone.